# Branching options menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

The other day I saw an application with a `branching options menu`. I searched a lot but didn't find any info. How can I create this?

Comment: branching options menu means?

Comment: @Agarwal clicking on a menu item opens up another branch of menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below link for your reference of createing menus and sub menus.

[LINK1](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.in/2009/11/creating-menu-submenu.html)

[LINK2](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/sub-menu/)

If nothing works then you can also try the below::

As can be seen in [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) sub menus can not contain sub menus.

You could show a Context menu after clicking on the item in the options menu. This could show your five more options in a floating view above the screen.

You have to overwrite the onCreateContextMenu to create a ContextMenu and I think you have to call the contextMenu manually in the onOptionsItemSelected method. For resources on how to create the context menu see this [paragraph](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) in the article mentioned above.

To open the ContextMenu you can call [openContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) in your Activity. You may need to register the menuitem before to enable your activity to find the correct context menu.